# Firestore orderBy mixed with query not working for pagination

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let currentDateTime = Date()

let time = Timestamp(date: currentDateTime)

guard let userUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return}

Firestore.firestore()
         .collection("\(user)/\(userUid)/\(timelinePath)")
         .order(by: "endDate").start(after: [lastKey ?? ""])
         .whereField("endDate", isLessThan: time).limit(to: 5)
```

I am trying to order using an endDate field, which is a timestamp and then get only the data with the date that has passed, which I check with the query `whereField`. The problem seems at the orderby. It does not order timestamp. Can this be fixed or is there a different way of doing this?

Edit - is there it possible to order by TimeStamp? I cant order with anything else since the first query is by timestamp the order has to follow the same query

[image: Here is my data structure]

Comment: Please edit the question to illustrate the contents of the database, the exact code you're using (formatted as code - what you have now is not formatted), and the results that are not what you expect.  You're probably doing something wrong, but without seeing all the data, it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0):

This may help. The following code sets up a timestamp date and will retrieve all events prior to that time from FireStore.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd"
let dateString = "2019/02/20"
let timestamp = formatter.date(from: dateString)

let timelineRef = self.db.collection("Timeline")
    .order(by: "endDate")
    .whereField("endDate", isLessThan: timestamp)
    // you can add .limit(to: 3) if you only want the 3 oldest for example

timelineRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            let docId = document.documentID
            let name = document.get("selfKey") as! String
            print(selfKey)
        }
    }
}
```